# Difference between Handshake exception and Connection Refused exception

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, client-server

I use a Jetty server with a threadpool of over 50 and serves around 200 encrypted requests everyday. When there is a sudden spike in the number of requests, some of the requests fail with either

```
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Handshake did not complete within 10000ms
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
```

or

```
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: <hostname>/IP
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$1.run(SslHandler.java:372) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:?]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:556) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:?]
```

Could someone help me in understanding the difference between both of these errors and how can it be rectified?

Answer (score 2):

*"Connection refused"* means that the client could not create a TCP connection to the server while *"SSLException: Handshake did not complete within ... "*  means that the TCP connection could be created but the server did not complete the SSL handshake within the given time (10s). The TCP handshake is done by the OS kernel  but only up to a specific number of outstanding connections which are not handled by the server application yet (size of listen queue) while the TLS handshake is done inside the application.

Given that the problem occurs only when there is a spike in the number of requests it means that your system is unable to handle this spike, i.e. it is overloaded. This might be because your system is not fast enough (CPU), has too few memory (i.e. gets over limit on spikes and needs to swap to disk) or that the  amount done for each request is too high. In case each of the threads is doing a lot of work it might also be that the amount of requests you get in the spike exceeds the number of available threads too much.

To fix it you need to find out what of these problems is the real cause and tune your system accordingly, i.e. use a faster CPU, more memory, do less work for each request or use more threads.